# How to run libreoffice via ssh with x11-forwarding

Tags: command-line, ssh, libreoffice, x11-forwarding

I am trying to launch `loffice` or `localc` via an established ssh connection (ForwardX11 enabled). It does however fail to show the loffice gui / splashscreen on the computer from where I run my ssh session. The `loffice` application runs in the remote bash but without any command line output.

All other gui applications like xterm, gvim, PyQt5 scripts work fine.
I also tried to run

```
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin
```

directly, but to no avail. (loffice is a shell script redirecting to another shell script, which as far as I understand eventually launches soffice.bin.)

Also without any success I tried:

```
loffice --display ${DISPLAY}
```

Comment: If there's a running LibreOffice program on the remote system, have you tried killing it?

Comment: The `--display` switch was what I needed. I noticed (via x11vnc) that there were instances running on the default display, but even after killing them, LibreOffice started on DISPLAY 0.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a LibreOffice window is open, it opens a window in the display of that process. Therefore one way would be to kill any running LibreOffice processes.

Comment: >:)  Good one!!!